# ZF2 read HTTP Cookie

Tags: php, zend-framework, cookies, http-headers, httpresponse

I have a file (caller.php) which create a cookie in HTTP response and then redirect to a controller in a ZF2 application (LoginController).

**caller.php**

```
setcookie("_ga", "GA1.2.1622977711.1433494392");
setcookie("_gat", "1");

header("Location: http://gnsys.local/publico/login");
```

**LoginController**

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Http\Response;

class LoginController extends BasePublicController{

public function indexAction(){

    $response = $this->getResponse();

    foreach ($response->getHeaders() as $header) {
        echo "Campo: " . $header->getFieldName() . ' with value ' . $header->getFieldValue() . "<br />";
    }


    return new ViewModel();
}
}
```

When LoginController is called, I haven't got any header from the HTTP response.

What am I doing wrong? Why I can't read any value from my http response headers? How can I read all the headers from HTTP Response?

If I do what I want but just only using PHP, LoginController is changed by a file called login.php whith this code:

```
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value</br>";
}
```

And this code works fine and give me what I want. How can I get the same in Zend Framework 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should extract headers from request, but not response:

```
foreach ($this->getRequest()->getHeaders() as $header) {
   echo 'Campo: ' . $header->getFieldName() . ' with value ' . $header->getFieldValue() . '<br />';
}
```

To get cookies only use next:

```
foreach ($this->getRequest()->getCookie() as $name => $value) {
    echo 'Campo: ' . $name . ' with value ' . $value . '<br />';
}
```

Set cookie from action:

```
public function callerAction()
{
    $cookie = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie();
    $cookie->setName('foo')
        ->setValue('bar')
        ->setDomain('gnsys.local')
        ->setPath('/')
        ->setHttponly(true);

    /** @var \Zend\Http\Response $response */
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie);

    return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/publico/login');
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! It works fine but I don't get the value of the cookie. Please, see my next answer!!!

Comment: Sorry, but I'm trying to create the cookie just only with php and not under zf2. Is there any problem with that?

Comment: Hi!!! If I make the caller with ZF2 the result that I get it's the same that If I make the caller with a php file (caller.php). This is what I've got: Campo: zdt-hidden with value 0

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while to get the cookie setting and reading correctly on a `Zend Framework 2` environment.

I created these two functions in a controller:

```
private function setCookie($name, $value) {
    $cookie = new SetCookie($name, $value, time() + 3600, '/');
    $this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie);
}

private function getCookie($name) {
    $cookie = $this->getRequest()->getCookie();
    if ($cookie->offsetExists($name)) {
        return $cookie->offsetGet($name);
    }
}
```

And I use them to keep a form field value across reloads as in:

```
$email_search = $this->params()->fromPost('email_search', '');
$is_submitted = $this->params()->fromPost('is_submitted', '');
if ($is_submitted) {
    $this->setCookie('user_list_email_search', $email_search);
} else {
    $email_search = $this->getCookie('user_list_email_search');
}
$form->get('email_search')->setValue($email_search);
```

The is_submitted form field is a static hidden flag:

```
<input type="hidden" name="is_submitted" value="1">
```

It is to allow the operator to reset to blank the email field.

There is a simpler alternative possible, in checking for a form filed being set or not, this time without any is_submitted hidden field:

```
$posts = $this->params()->fromPost();
if (isset($posts['email_search'])) {
    $email_search = $posts['email_search'];
    $this->setCookie('user_list_email_search', $email_search);
} else {
    $email_search = $this->getCookie('user_list_email_search');
}
$form->get('email_search')->setValue($email_search);
```

It all rests on the `isset($posts[` construct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my zf2-cookie plugin controller module to read/write cookies.

### Installation:

`composer require mikica/zf2-cookie`

You need to register new module. Add in file config/application.config.php:

`'modules' => array(
    '...',
    'ZfCookie'
),`

### Usage in controller

`$this->cookie('key'); //read cookie`

`$this->cookie('key','value'); //write cookie`